# How to search user manager name in identityNow by using search sailpoint

Tags: json, powershell, postman, sailpoint

I would like build a search query in IdentityNow for a user in Sailpoint

- to find out user manager name
- when manager name added removed or new manager added
- any changes have made to manager attibute

I have tried

Attributes.manager:"username"

But its not giving any results